# @PostConstruct initialize is not getting invoked implicitly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Using -Primefaces 3.4 + JSF 2.0-
I am displaying some drop down values from database and the Postconstruct initialize method is not getting invoke implicitly. 
Its working when I am calling the init method from other bean.
xhtml code:

```
<p:panelGrid style="width:50%" styleClass="panelgrid">
    <p:row>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="width:10%">#{msgs.partTypeTitle}</p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="partTypeDpDnId" value="#{ppcrDetails.newPpcr.selectedPartType}" style="width:150px;font-size:13px;" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrDetails.newPpcr.partsType}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="width:25%">#{msgs.familyTitle}</p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnB">     
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="familyDpDnId" value="#{ppcrDetails.newPpcr.selectedFamilyValues}" style="width:150px;font-size:13px;">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrDetails.newPpcr.familyValues}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
```

-Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "newPpcr" , eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class NewPpcr implements Serializable {
@PostConstruct
    public void initialize() throws QtException {

        LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG, "QuotationTool: NewPpcr initilize.");

        partsType.clear();
        List<MdPartsType> partList = partsTypeFacade.findAll();
        int partSequence = 0;
        for (MdPartsType part : partList) {
            partsType.add(new SelectItem(partSequence++, part.getPartType()));
        }

        familyValues.clear();
        List<MdFamily> familyList = familyFacade.findAll();
        int familySequence = 0;
        for (MdFamily family : familyList) {
            familyValues.add(new SelectItem(familySequence++, family.getFamily()));
        }

    }
```

But this is not working, So I am calling initialize method from other bean then drop down is populating:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ppcrDetails", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class PpcrDetails implements Serializable{
    private List<SelectItem> partType = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        private List<SelectItem> familyValues = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();


        public List<SelectItem> getPartType() {
            try {
                partType.clear();
                if (partType == null || partType.isEmpty()) {
                    newPpcr.initialize();
                    this.partType = newPpcr.getPartsType();
                }
            } catch (QtException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return partType;
        }

        public void setPartType(List<SelectItem> partType) {
            this.partType = partType;
        }

        public List<SelectItem> getFamilyValues() {
            try {
                familyValues.clear();
                if (familyValues == null || familyValues.isEmpty()) {
                    newPpcr.initialize();
                    this.familyValues = newPpcr.getFamilyValues();
                }
            } catch (QtException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return familyValues;
        }

        public void setFamilyValues(List<SelectItem> familyValues) {
            this.familyValues = familyValues;
}
```

From this approach I am able to display the values but it is breaking the some functionality.

Comment: You forgot to show how you're obtaining/injecting the `newPpcr` bean inside `ppcrDetails`.

Comment: Which application server do you use?

Comment: @ BalusC - using @ManagedProperty -               @ManagedProperty(value = "#{newPpcr}")
private NewPpcr newPpcr;                                                    @ Xtreme Biker - IBM WAS 8.5.5.0

Comment: would you post the ppcrDetails Class Code completely?important are local attributes declaration, methods incl. getter and setter, not the inner code

Comment: @Rami.Q - its huge file, can you let me know if you want to see some specific?

Comment: i'll try to point you to some points in an answer

Comment: @Rami.Q - This is the complete file as you can see I am calling the init method of the newPpcr in getter of the "private List<SelectItem> partType = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();" and this is the way init menthod getting invoked explicitly other way is <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.methodname()}"/> fromm the xhtml file.